# Using numpy arrays with root_scalar() from Python scipy.optimize

Tags: python, numpy, scipy-optimize

I need to solve a differential equation using solve_ivp() which works with numpy arrays. Some of the functions in by model are defined implicitly, so I need to invert them using root_scalar(), which works with a scalar value only, not with numpy arrays.

I want to create a wrapper root_numpy() that for some arguments accepts both scalar and array-like arguments.

```
def root_numpy(func, x0, ...):

# if x0 is scalar
    return sci_opt.root_scalar(func, x0=x0, ...)

# else create the results array, iterate over x0 and fill the results array ...
```

**First question**: How is this condition "if x0 is scalar" expressed with Python?

**Second question**: Isn't there a generic way to create such a wrapper that works with other functions in scipy as well?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not made to write code for you. With what part do you have problems, and what have you already tried?

Comment: Regarding the second question: I am curious if it's possible to create a kind of generic wrapper that works for **all** functions accepting scalar arguments only.

Comment: I would suggest you create a new SO question for this. This way the questions will be separated which is useful if someone else searches for it.

Comment: when you say "create the results array, iterate over x0 and fill the results array" you mean by repeated use of `root_scalar`?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I am doing and it works fine. (in my case I can use the result for entry to feed it into the bracket for the next one, so I narrow the interval)

Comment: So why don't you use a vectorized solver like `fsolve` or `root` and convert your input with `x0 = np.atleast_1d(x0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume that with scalar you mean a simple `float` number, then one way of solving your problem is:

```
def root_numpy(func, x0, ...):

if isinstance(x0, float):
    return sci_opt.root_scalar(func, x0=x0, ...)
else:
    # create the results array, iterate over x0 and fill the results array ...
```

Not that you can change the `float` in the `isinstance` function with any datatype you want.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime, I figured out another option. See my second answer. Would that be OK?

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is for the first question is

```
    if np.isscalar(x_ast):
        return sci_opt.root_scalar(inv_eq, args=(x_ast,), bracket=[1.0, 2.0], method='brentq'))    # currently I do not treat the bracket as an arguments and as an array yet
 
    # else: do the rest: create the results array, iterate over x0 and fill the results array ...
```

That works fine for my purposes, but does not answer the second question.